# Perform the battle of monsters in Python : calculate the winner in Heroes Might and Magic

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key, hero

I would like to simulate a battle of monsters from Heroes Might & Magic.
The problem is that only my monster no.2 (unicorn) loss his points.
What I'm doing wrong ?

Fighting mechanics explanation:

```
mon1 = {"type": "Roc",     "hitpoints": 40, "number": 6, "damage":8 }
mon2 = {"type": "Unicorn", "hitpoints": 40, "number": 4, "damage":13}
```

1. The Rocs attack the Unicorns for 48 damage (6 * 8),
   killing one and damaging the next - leaving it with 32/40 hitpoints.
2. The remaining 3 Unicorns attack the Rocs for 39 damage (3 * 13),
   killing 0 but leaving the first one with only 1/40 hitpoints.
3. Repeat until one of the groups is left with 0 units in total.

code

```
import math
def who_would_win(mon1, mon2):
    mon1 = {'type': "Roc", 'hitpoints': 40, 'number': 6, 'damage' : 8 }
    mon2 = {'type': "Unicorn", 'hitpoints': 40, 'number': 4, 'damage' : 13}
    while mon1['number'] > 0 and mon2['number'] > 0:
        mon2['hitpoints']*mon2['number']-mon1['damage']*mon1['number']
        mon2['number'] = int(math.ceil((mon2['hitpoints']*mon2['number']-mon1['damage']*mon1['number'])/mon2['hitpoints']))
        mon1['hitpoints']*mon1['number']-mon2['damage']*mon2['number']
        mon1['number'] = int(math.ceil((mon1['hitpoints']*mon1['number']-mon2['damage']*mon2['number'])/mon1['hitpoints']))
        if mon1['number'] > 0 and mon2['number'] <= 0:
            return (f'{mon1["number"]} {mon1["type"]}(s) won')
        if mon2['number'] > 0 and mon1['number'] <= 0:
            return (f'{mon2["number"]} {mon2["type"]}(s) won')
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: `mon2['hitpoints']*mon2['number']-mon1['damage']*mon1['number']` and `mon1['hitpoints']*mon1['number']-mon2['damage']*mon2['number']` do nothing useful. That just returns some value but you don't do anything with it. Nobody's hit points change at all.

Comment: Compare that to what you're doing with `mon2['number']` and `mon1['number']`.